# Smartphone battery: safe for (further) use?

Tags: batteries, smartphones

I disassembled my smartphone, which required removing the (non-removable) battery. The battery was glued with double-sided adhesive tape to some housing on the board. Further, there was some 'metallic' sticker across the battery and a metallic component on the board.

1. In order to remove the battery, it had to be bended a bit due to the adhesive tape. Not much, but you could feel that there was some bending going on (few mm)*. Further, the bottom of the battery wrapping seemed to deformed a bit due to the tape. My question is if the battery potentially could have taken some damage due to the removal and might self-ignite, explode, whatever, when I keep using it.
2. I'm curious if that metallic sticker has some purpose, or if it just some seal. The sticker itself is quite thin, and I couldn't remove it without breaking/disconnecting the battery and the metallic component. I'd like to know if there might result some potential danger if I remove the sticker completely.

   - *edit: Though the bending wasn't much, it was an elastic (rather than a plastic) deformation (battery went back to original shape after stress)

Attached two images showing the battery.

[image: front]
[image: back]

Answer (score 2):

Please follow proper disposal procedures for the used cell phone battery. The risk of damage is just too high.

You can purchase new similar batteries for very reasonable prices from Adafruit or Sparkfun.